# How to order HTTP Error Status Codes according to amount of data they contain

Tags: http, network-programming

I am trying to understand the data amount of HTTP status error codes and comparision of them with each other: (200,301,400,505,404).I can easily find the definitions of them but I could'dnt find this information anywhere.

For example: 200 is the biggest one because it has all the data.

What I am looking for: 200>-->-->-->--

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense.  Any error code can return any amount of data it wants.  A 500 could range from an empty message to a complete diagnostic of the system, depending on what the web designer wants.  This information doesn't exist because it's not really a question.

Comment: @FrankYellin Sir my lecturer at the university answered like this: 200 maximum information. Next comes the 301.
400 bad request, that is, I did not understand what he said. Therefore, it has the least information.
505 http version does not support. Therefore, it cannot process the remainder of the request. If it's 404, it's not found, so I couldn't find the page you're looking for. Therefore, it knows the desired page. This is the most information out of 3 of them.
The order will be logically 400, 505, 404, 301.

Comment: I did not understand it either and I am looking for a logical explanation.

Comment: I have no idea what s/he means.  Maybe someone else on SO does.

Comment: What does this have to do with [assembly] language, like x86 `imul eax, ecx, 12345`?  Or did you mean to tag [web-assembly]?  If so, how is the question related to that?  I've removed all the tags that don't make sense based on their mouseover usage information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict or logical order to the amount of data contained in various HTTP response codes.  At best I would divide them into three buckets:

## Typically large

`200 OK` is likely to have the largest average payload. A server returns this status when it returns a document. This is going to be the status returned when downloading large images, books, video, or large pages.  There can also be very small such responses when the document requested is very small.

## Medium sized - custom error pages

Error status like `404 Not Found`, `410 Gone`, and `500 Internal Server error` have very small default payloads from web servers.  However, it is very common for sites to provide custom pages for these errors. A custom error page typically has the look and feel of the rest of the website and may contain debugging information and additional navigation to help the user.

## Small size

Other responses are typically very small and not usually customized by sites.  For example the response for a 301 redirect could be as small as

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/
```

however servers typically also include a handful of other headers and a very small HTML document containing only a link to the new location.

Comment: Sir, My lecturer at the university answered like this: 200 maximum information. Next comes the 301. 400 bad request, that is, I did not understand what he said. Therefore, it has the least information. 505 http version does not support. Therefore, it cannot process the remainder of the request. If it's 404, it's not found, so I couldn't find the page you're looking for. Therefore, it knows the desired page. This is the most information out of 3 of them. The order will be logically 400, 505, 404, 301. I couldn't understand the logic behind this.

Comment: @Mehmet: Are you sure your lecturer is talking about the number of total bytes in the response, rather than some other meaning of the word "information"?  Like how useful the information is to a client?  Probably you should talk to them, maybe show them this Q&A and Stephen's answer, so they can clarify what they meant.